# useSelector and map function React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

i want to iterate through an array but Im not sure if i can do this in the useSelector redux hook because it's not giving me the result that i want.  Have any of you ever achieved this? or am i going about it completely wrong?

index.jsx

```
const test = useSelector(state => state.data.map(e => e.details));
```

data.js

```
    data: [
        {
            name: 'long neck',
            details: {
                total: 1,
                height: "3ft",
                weight: "34 lbs",               
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'fun fact',
            details: {
                total: 30,
                height: '1ft',
                weight: '16 lbs',
            }
        },
    ],
```

Comment: Can you add more details around what you're trying to accomplish, and what isn't working? What is `data.js` used for?

Comment: What's the structure of state.queueCounts?

Comment: doing that will cause your component be constantly rendering no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I my opinion you should not do that.

Because you are returning a new array every time the useSelector gets called.

The right way in my opinion is to return the actual data and then do the filtering outside like this.

```
const data = useSelector(state => state.data);

const details = calculateDetails() => {

   //do all your filtering, mapping, slicing
   return data.map(e => e.details));
};
```

The reason I do it this way is to avoid rendering when nothing has changed.

You should not return new objects out of a useSelector unless you use the second parameter which is an equality checking funcion.

Comment: that's valid point, but I'm afraid, that OP's "not giving me result I want" is not about extra re-renders after every `dispatch()` call

Comment: @skyboyer he is asking if he should or not iterate over an array and return a transformed result from the useSelector... and I answered you should not and why